# `wreq` Get / Post with exception handling

Tags: haskell

I am  making some http calls using `wreq` and would like to catch any exception and return an `Either` type. I tried something like this but could not figure out how to manipulate the calls so it will type check.

```
 -- exhaustive pattern match omitted here
 safeGetUrl :: URL -> Maybe Login -> Maybe Password -> IO (Either String (Response LBS.ByteString))
 safeGetUrl url (Just login) (Just pass) = do
     let def  = defaults
         opts = def & auth ?~ basicAuth (BS.pack login) (BS.pack pass)
     r <- getWith opts url  `E.catch` handler
     return $ Right r

   where
     handler :: HttpException -> Either String (Response LBS.ByteString)
     handler (StatusCodeException s _ _) = do
          return $ Left $ LBS.unpack (s ^. statusMessage)
```

I am pasting the type error below but I know the above code will not compile. The issue is `r <- getWith opts url`  `E.catch` `handler`. The first part returns `IO (Res...` but the exception handler returns `Either..`. I tried adding lifting the `getWith..` into `Either` but that did not type check either.

```
Couldn't match type ‘Either String (Response LBS.ByteString)’
                 with ‘IO (Response LBS.ByteString)’
  Expected type: HttpException -> IO (Response LBS.ByteString)
    Actual type: HttpException
                 -> Either String (Response LBS.ByteString)
  In the second argument of ‘catch’, namely ‘handler’
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: r <- getWith opts url `catch` handler
```

Is there a way to catch this exception and return an `IO Either` type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that one side of the handle returns an unwrapped response (no `Either`) and the other side returns an `Either`-wrapped exception. You then attempt to wrap the response in an `Either`, which you do need to do, but it's just at the wrong place. You can fix this merely by switching  where you do the wrapping

```
safeGetUrl :: URL -> Maybe Login -> Maybe Password -> IO (Either String (Response LBS.ByteString))
 safeGetUrl url (Just login) (Just pass) = do
     let def  = defaults
         opts = def & auth ?~ basicAuth (BS.pack login) (BS.pack pass)
     (Right <$> getWith opts url) `E.catch` handler

   where
     handler :: HttpException -> IO (Either String (Response LBS.ByteString))
     handler (StatusCodeException s _ _) = do
          return $ Left $ LBS.unpack (s ^. statusMessage)
```

However there are some other problems with your functions, remember that `unpack` gives back `Word8`s not `Char`. You may want to import `Data.ByteString.Char` as the version of `unpack` defined in there should work better than `LBS.unpack`. Without your imports though I cannot confirm this definitively. The final (working) code for me is

```
import Control.Lens
import Network.Wreq
import Network.HTTP.Client
import qualified Control.Exception as E
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BSC
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LBS

type URL = String
type Login = String
type Password = String

safeGetUrl :: URL
           -> Maybe Login
           -> Maybe Password
           -> IO (Either String (Response LBS.ByteString))
safeGetUrl url (Just login) (Just pass) = do
  let def  = defaults
      opts = def & auth ?~ basicAuth (BSC.pack login) (BSC.pack pass)
  (Right <$> getWith opts url)  `E.catch` handler
  where
    handler :: HttpException -> IO (Either String (Response LBS.ByteString))
    handler (StatusCodeException s _ _) = do
      return $ Left $ BSC.unpack (s ^. statusMessage)
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to `lift` `getWith` and somehow I could not figure out how to do it. I am still at the beginner stage in Haskell so did not immediately see how I can just use `<$>` to wrap the response inside Either.  Regarding the `BSC` vs. `LBS`... that was an oversight on my part -- thanks for pointing it it out.

Answer (score 6):

Since @jozefg answer, the API has changed a little bit and the answer doesn't compile anymore.

Here is an updated version that compiles:

```hs
import qualified Control.Exception     as E
import           Control.Lens
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BSC
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy  as LBS
import           Network.HTTP.Client
import           Network.Wreq          as NW

type URL = String

type Login = String

type Password = String

safeGetUrl ::
     URL
  -> Maybe Login
  -> Maybe Password
  -> IO (Either String (Response LBS.ByteString))
safeGetUrl url (Just login) (Just pass) = do
  let def = defaults
      opts = def & auth ?~ basicAuth (BSC.pack login) (BSC.pack pass)
  (Right <$> getWith opts url) `E.catch` handler
  where
    handler :: HttpException -> IO (Either String (Response LBS.ByteString))
    handler (HttpExceptionRequest _ (StatusCodeException r _)) =
      return $ Left $ BSC.unpack (r ^. NW.responseStatus . statusMessage)
```